# SSL redirection based on folder and domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ssl, https

This seems like such an easy thing, yet I am having such trouble with it. I have a development server and a live server, I push, via git, from the dev server to live server once changes are tested etc...

I am using the following in my htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(members/.*)$ https://live-domain.com/members/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Which works a treat on the live domain. But now when I go to **dev-domain.com/members**, it redirects to the **https://live-domain.com**.

What I need is it only to go to https if the members folder is called and it is live-comain.com. So I tried the following, and variants of:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*\.)?live-domain\.com
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(members/.*)$ https://live-domain.com/members/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But the above just times-out with an infinite loop error message on **live-domain.com**, and /members/members/members/members/members/ etc... in the url

Could someone please point me in the right direction so the https rewrite only occurs on live-domain.com.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else come across this question, my resolution is below.

There were various problems, the main one being I did not realise that Amazon AWS (Where my live site is) does not pass http or https info from the load balancer(where the SSL cert is) to the EC2 instance(where my script is).

You need to use HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto to detect that. Full working htaccess below:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*\.)?live-domain\.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} members 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://live-domain.com/members/$1 [R,L]
```

The above is in the htaccess file within the members directory.

Hope it helps.